# Tracking Custom metrics / dimensions in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics-api

I have a single page application built on Angularjs. The tracker seems to be working fine. How  do i capture custom metrics say 'Searched Keywords' in my application.?

I am using analytics.js.

This code dosent seem to work. Custom dimension 'Usersearch' not being tracked.

```
var userDimensionValue = $rootScope.user.search;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', { 'Usersearch': userDimensionValue });
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the user scoped custom dimension in the web interface. And your code should look something like [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets).

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  'userDimensionValue'
});
```

Where dimension1 corresponds to the first dimension you created.